# Understanding of the definition of a Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, tangent-bundle

I have have an exercise where it says:

Let $M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x_2>0\}$ with metric $g=\dfrac{1}{x_2^2}((dx_1)^2+(dx_2)^2)$.

Now I have trouble understanding how this metric works, let for example $a,b$ be tangent vectors in $M$. Then what is $g(a,b)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form $dx_1$ selects the first component of a vector $a=(a_1,a_2).$ So $dx_1(a)=a_1.$ The notation $(dx_1)^2$ is shorthand for $dx_1\otimes dx_1$. So $(dx_1)^2(a,b) = dx_1\otimes dx_1(a,b) = a_1\cdot b_1.$

Therefore $g(a,b)=(a_1\cdot b_1 + a_2\cdot b_2)/x_2^2,$ where $x_2$ is the second coordinate of the basepoint of the tangent vectors $a$ and $b$.

By the way it may interest you to know the metric given is the [Poincaré half plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model).

Comment: Yes thank you very much, that answers my questions. I always have trouble understanding the notation.